# Laravel Websockets dashboard base path with sub folder not working

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am quite new to broadcasting/websockets and I am attempting to set up Laravel Websockets and pusher.

Using my `subdomain.example.com` I can get `subdomain.example.com/laravel-websockets` working and events get listed on the screen when I fire them using php artisan tinker and when I create an event on the page. However I need this work inside a path `subdomain.example.com/api/laravel-websockets`

When I try the url with `/api` although it loads the dashboard as expected it fails to connect and from looking in the console I can see it is ignoring the `/api` in its requests, e.g. for Auth: `http://subdomain.example.com/laravel-websockets/auth` instead of `http://subdomain.example.com/api/laravel-websockets/auth`. This applies to everything in the console. Even when I edit the request in the console to add the `/api` it works.

Is there somewhere I can change the base path?

Here is my `.env` file:

```
APP_URL=http://subdomain.example.com/api/

LOG_CHANNEL=daily

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

APP_NAME==test
PUSHER_APP_ID=1234
PUSHER_APP_KEY=1234
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=secret
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Here is my `config/websockets.php` pusher config

```
'dashboard' => [
    'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
],

'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

and my `config/broadcasting.php`

```
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http'
    ],
],
```

**Edit:** Adding my config to show how /api is working where `/var/www/example` is the root folder of my Laravel application

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
    Alias /api /var/www/example/public
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine On
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/client-side
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

in public/.htaccess I have the following:

```
 RewriteBase /api/
```

**Edit**

I see that I can get this working if I add `api/` to the javascript request paths right in the `dashboard.blade.php` which makes me think the solution is have a version of that file running. However I dont think this solves the overall issue. I would rather do this correctly. (see `authEndpoint` below)

```
     connect() {
            this.pusher = new Pusher(this.app.key, {
                wsHost: this.app.host === null ? window.location.hostname : this.app.host,
                wsPort: this.port === null ? 6001 : this.port,
                wssPort: this.port === null ? 6001 : this.port,
                wsPath: this.app.path === null ? '' : this.app.path,
                disableStats: true,
                authEndpoint: '/api/{{ request()->path() }}/auth',
                auth: {
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                        'X-App-ID': this.app.id
                    }
                },
                enabledTransports: ['ws', 'flash']
            });
```

Comment: You cannot just change the path and expect for it to work. You’ve got to change the routing handling of that path as well. See config/websockets.php file that has a path for web sockets handling.

Comment: I presume you're not talking about the path in config/websockets.php? As that is working fine as just 'laravel-websockets' as expected. if I change it to 'api/laravel-websockets' that breaks my url. Its not that I cant load the url its that base path is still using just the domain. Thanks for the help, and sorry Im new to this concept!

Comment: I will edit the question to also add my virtual hosts configuation

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Laravel 6.x and in `dashboard.blade.php` I replaced `request()->path()` with `Request::getRequestUri()` on line 121 and 165, that provides a dynamic solution, but I still had to orderride the vendor `dashboard.blade.php` file... so opened an issue on github.

Answer (score 1):

I will not mark this as the answer until someone has a better suggestion but I had to override `dashboard.blade.php` and make my own one in `resources/views/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/dashboard.blade.php` and add `/api` where all calls are made.

This actually fixed another issue I was having too in relation to not getting the real time graph.

Answer (score 0):

The default location of the WebSocket dashboard is at /laravel-websockets. The routes get automatically registered. You can change the default location by changing the path setting in your **config/websockets.php** file.

Change from:

```
/*
 * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.
 */
'path' => 'laravel-websockets',
```

To:

```
/*
 * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.
 */
'path' => 'api/laravel-websockets',
```